# Making 2 Modifications to a Bubblesort Program

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I have to make the following 2 modifications to a simple bubblesort program:

1. After the first pass, the largest number is guaranteed to be in the highest-numbered element of the array; after the second pass, the two highest numbers are “in place”; and so on. Instead of making nine comparisons on every pass, modify the bubble sort to make eight comparisons on the second pass, seven on the third, and so on.
2. The data in the array may already be in the proper order or near proper order, so why make nine passes if fewer will suffice? Modify the sort to check at the end of each pass if any swaps have been made. If none have been made, the data must already be in the proper order, so the program should terminate. If swaps have been made, at least one more pass is needed."

Any help as to how I should approach these would be greatly appreciated!

```
//sort elements of array with bubble sort
public static void bubbleSort (int array2[])
{

    //loop to control number of passes
    for (int pass = 1; pass < array2.length; pass++)
    {

        //loop to control number of comparisons
        for (int element = 0; element < array2.length - 1; element++)
        {

            //compare side-by-side elements and swap them if 
            //first element is greater than second element
            if (array2[element] > array2[element + 1]){

                swap (array2, element, element + 1);

            }
        }
    }
}
//swap two elements of an array
public static void swap (int array3[], int first, int second)
{
    //temporary holding area for swap
    int hold;
    hold = array3[first];
    array3[first] = array3[second];
    array3[second] = hold;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do for you. A boolean is added to check and the run (`j`) is subtracted from the `input.length` for each run.

```
public static int[] bubbleSort(int input[])
{
    int i, j, tmp;
    bool changed;
    for (j = 0; j < input.length; j++)
    {
        changed = false;
        for (i = 1; i < input.length - j; i++)
        {
            if (tmp[i-1] > input[i])
            {
                tmp= input[i];
                input[i] = input[i-1];
                input[i-1] = tmp;
                changed = true;
            }
        }
        if (!changed) return input;
    }
    return input;
}
```